# SD card not working :[ 249.480884] mmc0: error -5 whilst initialising SD card

Tags: 16.04, sd-card, modprobe, lspci, mmc

I have an issue with my recent Ubuntu. Actually I have all drivers (USB, WiFi, etc ) working fine however when I insert the SD I can't detect it.

Also I find the following error kernel log:

```
[  242.936702] mmc0: error -5 whilst initialising SD card
[  244.856671] mmc0: error -5 whilst initialising SD card
[  245.756789] mmc0: error -5 whilst initialising SD card
[  246.657133] mmc0: error -5 whilst initialising SD card
[  248.577135] mmc0: error -5 whilst initialising SD card
[  249.480884] mmc0: error -5 whilst initialising SD card
```

Below some useful details about my pc:

```
uname -a
```

**`Linux smarto-pc 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`**

```
lspci -v
```

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: hsw_uncore

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at  [disabled]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
    Memory at c0610000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo 8 Series USB xHCI HC
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
    Memory at c0600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 8 Series HECI
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at c0618000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 8 Series HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at c0614000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 40
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: c0500000-c05fffff
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 41
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: c0400000-c04fffff
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo 8 Series USB EHCI
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at c061c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 8 Series LPC Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Lenovo 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    I/O ports at 4088 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 4094 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 4080 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 4090 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 4060 [size=32]
    Memory at c061b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 8 Series SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 11
    Memory at c0619000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 4040 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at c0504000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at c0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Memory at c0400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

```
lsmod
```

```
Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   20480  2
rtsx_usb_ms            20480  0
intel_rapl             20480  0
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_usb_ms
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
kvm                   536576  0
uvcvideo               90112  0
bluetooth             520192  10 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,btintel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
wl                   6365184  0
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              176128  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
aesni_intel           167936  0
snd_hda_codec_conexant    24576  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_conexant
snd_soc_rt5640        114688  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
snd_hda_intel          36864  5
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5640
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_soc_core          212992  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
cfg80211              565248  1 wl
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
joydev                 20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
cryptd                 20480  2 aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
serio_raw              16384  0
snd_pcm               106496  7 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core
shpchp                 36864  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
ideapad_laptop         24576  0
mei_me                 36864  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
wmi                    20480  1 ideapad_laptop
dw_dmac                16384  0
dw_dmac_core           24576  1 dw_dmac
snd_soc_sst_acpi       16384  0
8250_fintek            16384  0
8250_dw                16384  0
snd                    81920  23 snd_soc_core,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_compress
lpc_ich                24576  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
elan_i2c               36864  0
soc_button_array       16384  0
i2c_designware_platform    16384  0
i2c_designware_core    20480  1 i2c_designware_platform
spi_pxa2xx_platform    24576  0
mac_hid                16384  0
mmc_block              36864  0
tifm_sd                20480  0
tifm_core              16384  1 tifm_sd
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
rtsx_usb_sdmmc         28672  0
rtsx_usb               24576  2 rtsx_usb_sdmmc,rtsx_usb_ms
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
i915                 1208320  5
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        139264  1 i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
psmouse               126976  0
ahci                   36864  2
drm                   360448  6 i915,drm_kms_helper
r8169                  81920  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
mii                    16384  1 r8169
sdhci_acpi             16384  0
video                  40960  2 i915,ideapad_laptop
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_acpi
i2c_hid                20480  0
hid                   118784  3 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid
fjes                   28672  0
```

Thanks a lot,

Comment: At kernel `4.15.0-45-generic` I get `error -110`, not `-5`, and the upvoted workaround from gconcon doesn't help. :/

Answer (score 5):

There is a kernel compatibility issue with some sd cards (mainly SDHC or SDXC).

A workaround is below, but the IO speed is about 10x lower :(

Write a file called /etc/modprobe.d/sdcard.conf with this content:

```
options sdhci debug_quirks2=0x2
```

Let's remove and probe some modules:

```
 sudo rmmod sdhci_acpi sdhci_pci sdhci
 sudo modprobe sdhci; sudo modprobe sdhci_acpi; sudo modprobe sdhci_pci
```

After this, your SD card must be shown at notification bar.

To save all this configurations, run:

```
 sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: use `0x4000` instead of `0x2`, this will probably be faster.

Comment: This didn't help for me at kernel `4.15.0-45-generic`. Do you have a source on what `debug_quirks2` is, and what the magic 0x2 value is?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall udisks2
```

then reboot the Linux.

Comment: Why would this help?

Comment: I see this and work for me. http://askubuntu.com/questions/787088/ubuntu-16-04-does-not-detect-sd-card-reader

Comment: @PabloFerreira: In that case you should link this question to the one in your comment and not simply duplicate the answer. Please note that the linked question describes quite different symptoms than this one.

Comment: That is why I said this again. I not upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04, I just did the clean install, but the problems is there in same way.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when using SDXC 128GB in Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.04. I 'd tried couple times to reinstall but the problem could not be solved. I inspected the format used, it was exfat. Then I reformatted using NTSF, and it is working now. May be you can try my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem in 19.04.  The recent kernel bump from 5.0.0-13 to -31 (`apt update && apt upgrade`) fixed it.