# ubuntu 16.04 won't detect SD card on dell e7440

Tags: drivers, 16.04, dell, automount, sd-card

Few days ago I had no problem burning xbian on a SD card, today I've tried to do it again on a fresh card and Ubuntu refused to detect that I've inserted it. I thought that the new card may be faulty and I've checked the old one and my computer couldn't detect it either.

When I insert the card simply nothing happens, no new messages in `dmesg`, no new devices in `/dev/`, just like nothing happened.

I keep my system (16.04) up-to-date and its currently running kernel 4.4.0-43-generic

My laptop is Dell Lattitude E7440 with builtin O2 Micro SD card reader.

It may or may not be related to a problem I had with freezing `docker`. Someone on the internet suggested to run:

```
sudo dmsetup mknodes
```

This tool certainly has something to do with memory devices and although it helped with the `docker` it may have broken something with SD card reader.

Now some diagnostics:

```
$ uname -a
Linux e7440 4.4.0-43-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 12 13:48:03 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

,

```
$ lspci
...
03:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
```

SD Card is present int the slot.

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   7,6G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  38,1G  0 part /
└─sda6   8:6    0   420G  0 part /home
```

,

```
$ grep -iE "sdhci|mmc" /var/log/syslog
Oct 16 20:04:02 e7440 kernel: [    0.110590] PCI: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] at [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff] (base 0xf8000000)
Oct 16 20:04:02 e7440 kernel: [    0.110592] PCI: MMCONFIG at [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff] reserved in E820
Oct 16 20:04:02 e7440 kernel: [    0.814775] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
Oct 16 20:04:02 e7440 kernel: [    0.814778] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
Oct 16 20:04:02 e7440 kernel: [    0.829377] sdhci-pci 0000:03:00.0: SDHCI controller found [1217:8520] (rev 1)
Oct 16 20:04:02 e7440 kernel: [    0.831379] mmc0: Unknown controller version (3). You may experience problems.
Oct 16 20:04:02 e7440 kernel: [    0.831393] sdhci-pci 0000:03:00.0: No vmmc regulator found
Oct 16 20:04:02 e7440 kernel: [    0.831395] sdhci-pci 0000:03:00.0: No vqmmc regulator found
Oct 16 20:04:02 e7440 kernel: [    0.837937] mmc0: SDHCI controller on PCI [0000:03:00.0] using ADMA
Oct 16 20:07:46 e7440 kernel: [    0.111881] PCI: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] at [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff] (base 0xf8000000)
Oct 16 20:07:46 e7440 kernel: [    0.111884] PCI: MMCONFIG at [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff] reserved in E820
Oct 16 20:07:46 e7440 kernel: [    0.815203] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
Oct 16 20:07:46 e7440 kernel: [    0.815204] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
Oct 16 20:07:46 e7440 kernel: [    0.830301] sdhci-pci 0000:03:00.0: SDHCI controller found [1217:8520] (rev 1)
Oct 16 20:07:46 e7440 kernel: [    0.832340] mmc0: Unknown controller version (3). You may experience problems.
Oct 16 20:07:46 e7440 kernel: [    0.832354] sdhci-pci 0000:03:00.0: No vmmc regulator found
Oct 16 20:07:46 e7440 kernel: [    0.832356] sdhci-pci 0000:03:00.0: No vqmmc regulator found
Oct 16 20:07:46 e7440 kernel: [    0.838082] mmc0: SDHCI controller on PCI [0000:03:00.0] using ADMA
Oct 16 20:09:53 e7440 kernel: [  132.501886] mmc0: Card removed during transfer!
Oct 16 20:09:53 e7440 kernel: [  132.501889] mmc0: Resetting controller.
Oct 16 20:17:01 e7440 kernel: [    0.111302] PCI: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] at [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff] (base 0xf8000000)
Oct 16 20:17:01 e7440 kernel: [    0.111305] PCI: MMCONFIG at [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff] reserved in E820
Oct 16 20:17:01 e7440 kernel: [    0.827957] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
Oct 16 20:17:01 e7440 kernel: [    0.827959] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
Oct 16 20:17:01 e7440 kernel: [    0.844377] sdhci-pci 0000:03:00.0: SDHCI controller found [1217:8520] (rev 1)
Oct 16 20:17:01 e7440 kernel: [    0.846390] mmc0: Unknown controller version (3). You may experience problems.
Oct 16 20:17:01 e7440 kernel: [    0.846405] sdhci-pci 0000:03:00.0: No vmmc regulator found
Oct 16 20:17:01 e7440 kernel: [    0.846407] sdhci-pci 0000:03:00.0: No vqmmc regulator found
Oct 16 20:17:01 e7440 kernel: [    0.849356] mmc0: SDHCI controller on PCI [0000:03:00.0] using ADMA
```

The `mmc0: Unknown controller version (3). You may experience problems.` was displayed even when the reader was working.

```
$ sudo dmsetup ls
No devices found
```

And

```
$ ls -l /dev | wc -l
```

reports same value before and after instering the card.

Comment: Have you rebooted the laptop since `dmsetup` command. If yes, it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Yes I have, multiple times.

Comment: Try to format the SD on a different device and try.

Comment: Both cards were verified on different machine, also with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: This might helps:
"Workaround for broken O2 Micro SD card reader support since Linux kernel version 4.1.8"
http://www.0xf8.org/2016/01/workaround-for-broken-o2-micro-sd-card-reader-support-since-linux-kernel-version-4-1-8/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you reinstall the udisks2 with the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall udisks2
```

[Ubuntu 16.04 does not detect sd card reader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787088/ubuntu-16-04-does-not-detect-sd-card-reader)

Comment: This does not work for me with the same problem. It seems to be a general problem that is still there with Kernel 4.4.x... ;(