# Lenovo Edge 15 not detecting SD cards in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: lenovo, sd-card

I have a Lenovo Edge 15 (80k9) running Ubuntu 16.04 and kernel `4.4.0-59-generic`. I've tried a number of different micro SD Cards (using two different micro-to-SD adapters) and none seem to be recognized by the internal SD reader.

Running `blkid` only shows `/dev/sda*` and lines relating to FDE, ditto `fdisk -l`.

I tried `dmesg` and searched for lines with "Card", "MMC", and "Reader" but nothing that seemed relevant appeared.

Output from `lsusb`

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 03eb:8a1d Atmel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:055e Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output from `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

I also tried reinstalling `udisk` based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/790308/334823)

Comment: What did you tried? Reinstalling `udisks2` or the Realtek driver? The other answers are BS. And by "adapter" you mean microSD to SD, right? Because if it is a USB reader then the troubleshooting may not be about the SD itself. Please edit your question and add the steps you already tried (do not just point to a multiple answer question) and also the results of `lsusb` and `lspci` in code tags. Thanks.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Updated based on your helpful suggestions