# Ubuntu 18.04 fails to mount SD card while Windows 10 reads it perfectly

Tags: drivers, mount, sd-card

The SD card is NTFS formatted.

Ubuntu 18.04 fails to mount SD card while Windows 10 reads it perfectly and reports no errors.

Actually, Ubuntu will not even boot with the SD card inserted. ANy ideas/Suggestions?

I know there are similar questions around, although in my case it has nothing (?) to do with SD card erroneous partitions or not functioning since it works perfectly under windows 10. None of the found answers to previous similar questions seem to apply her (!?)

Here's the dmesg output

```
[ 9872.433010] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[ 9872.433015] mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
[ 9872.433020] mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0x00000008 | Version:  0x00000603
[ 9872.433024] mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00000200 | Blk cnt:  0x00000008
[ 9872.433028] mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x0eb875b0 | Trn mode: 0x0000003b
[ 9872.433032] mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x01ff0000 | Host ctl: 0x00000017
[ 9872.433037] mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
[ 9872.433042] mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000007
[ 9872.433046] mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x0000000a | Int stat: 0x00000000
[ 9872.433050] mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x02ff008b | Sig enab: 0x02ff008b
[ 9872.433055] mmc0: sdhci: AC12 err:  0x00000004 | Slot int: 0x00000000
[ 9872.433059] mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x25bec8bf | Caps_1:   0x1000207f
[ 9872.433064] mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x0000123a | Max curr: 0x005800c8
[ 9872.433068] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000900 | Resp[1]:  0x20307470
[ 9872.433072] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x20202020 | Resp[3]:  0x00000b00
[ 9872.433075] mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x0000800b
[ 9872.433080] mmc0: sdhci: ADMA Err:  0x00000000 | ADMA Ptr: 0x34800208
[ 9872.433081] mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
[ 9872.433181] mmcblk0: error -110 sending stop command, original cmd response 0x0, card status 0x400900
[ 9872.433184] mmcblk0: error -110 transferring data, sector 246969776, nr 8, cmd response 0x0, card status 0x0
[ 9873.265026] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[ 9873.351446] mmcblk0: response CRC error sending r/w cmd command, card status 0x900
[ 9873.405031] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
```

Comment: Ubuntu could always detect but never mount any SD card from my laptops built in card reader, regardless of format. Hope you'll find your solution.

Comment: This looks like a driver issue perhaps, with the MMC controller in question. Do you have an alternate reader to try that you can connect via USB?

Comment: Yes, you are right! It is an MMC controller issue! The card is read mounted and read perfectly when using an exteranl USB reader! Thank you!

Comment: Does this solve it?: https://askubuntu.com/questions/787088/ubuntu-16-04-does-not-detect-sd-card-reader

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this help: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/hardware-cardreader.html.en  ?

Summary: open the Files app in the Activities list, and look under Other Activities for your sd card.

See also my question: [internal sd card reader works, but without automount](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058501/internal-sd-card-reader-works-but-without-automount/)

Comment: My problem appears at boot time. If I boot without an inserted card, it can be subsequently mounted once inserted

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly a driver issue. With the card in place, Ubuntu will not boot! However, removing the card and booting into Ubuntu, it will happily (alas under protest!) mount the card and work just fine with it, both writing and reading flawlessly!

So this is the workaround:

(1) remove the card and boot,

(2) once booted, insert card.

Not happy, but at least in work mode  :-)

After all upgrades since the first post, the messages have slightly changed to the following now:

```
[   45.792114] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[   45.792122] mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
[   45.792130] mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0x00000008 | Version:  0x00000603
[   45.792137] mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00000200 | Blk cnt:  0x00000008
[   45.792143] mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x0eb877f0 | Trn mode: 0x0000003b
[   45.792150] mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x01ff0000 | Host ctl: 0x00000017
[   45.792156] mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
[   45.792163] mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000007
[   45.792169] mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x0000000a | Int stat: 0x00000000
[   45.792175] mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x02ff008b | Sig enab: 0x02ff008b
[   45.792181] mmc0: sdhci: AC12 err:  0x00000004 | Slot int: 0x00000000
[   45.792188] mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x25bec8bf | Caps_1:   0x1000207f
[   45.792195] mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x0000123a | Max curr: 0x005800c8
[   45.792201] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000900 | Resp[1]:  0x20307470
[   45.792208] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x20202020 | Resp[3]:  0x00000900
[   45.792212] mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x0000800b
[   45.792218] mmc0: sdhci: ADMA Err:  0x00000000 | ADMA Ptr: 0x34400208
[   45.792221] mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
[   45.792336] mmcblk0: error -84 sending status command, retrying
[   45.848023] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[   45.848080] mmcblk0: error -110 sending stop command, original cmd response 0x0, card status 0x900
[   45.848084] mmcblk0: error -110 transferring data, sector 246970352, nr 8, cmd response 0x0, card status 0x0
[   47.420016] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[   47.439278] mmcblk0: response CRC error sending r/w cmd command, card status 0x900
[   47.492021] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[   47.497364] mmcblk0: response CRC error sending r/w cmd command, card status 0x900
[   47.556026] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[   52.575443] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   52.575449] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   52.575454] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   62.432012] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[   62.432018] mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
[   62.432023] mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0x000000c0 | Version:  0x00000603
[   62.432027] mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00000200 | Blk cnt:  0x000000c0
[   62.432031] mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x0000005f | Trn mode: 0x0000003b
[   62.432035] mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x01ff0000 | Host ctl: 0x00000017
[   62.432040] mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
[   62.432044] mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000007
[   62.432048] mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x0000000a | Int stat: 0x00000000
[   62.432052] mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x02ff008b | Sig enab: 0x02ff008b
[   62.432057] mmc0: sdhci: AC12 err:  0x00000004 | Slot int: 0x00000000
[   62.432061] mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x25bec8bf | Caps_1:   0x1000207f
[   62.432065] mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x0000123a | Max curr: 0x005800c8
[   62.432069] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000900 | Resp[1]:  0x20307470
[   62.432074] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x20202020 | Resp[3]:  0x00000900
[   62.432076] mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x0000800b
[   62.432081] mmc0: sdhci: ADMA Err:  0x00000000 | ADMA Ptr: 0x34400208
[   62.432082] mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
[   62.432204] mmcblk0: error -84 sending status command, retrying
[   62.488013] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[   62.488087] mmcblk0: error -110 sending stop command, original cmd response 0x0, card status 0x900
[   62.488089] mmcblk0: error -110 transferring data, sector 95, nr 192, cmd response 0x0, card status 0x0
[   64.804015] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
```