# internal sd card reader works, but without automount

Tags: usb, automount, sd-card

On a new laptop I installed Ubuntu 18.04. Everything works fine, except for auto mount of sd cards. After inserting an sd card in the internal card reader, dmesg says:

```
mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address b368
mmcblk0: mmc0:b368       7.46 GiB 
mmcblk0: p1
mmcblk0: p1
```

The driver seems to be working OK because manually mounting works with:

```
sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt
```

However, this makes the sd card read-only for all normal users. From my old laptop with the previous version of ubuntu, I was used to usb drives that automatically mount to `/media/{user}/{volumename}` and that can be unmounted with a context mouse menu on the menu icon for the drive.

My questions are:

- how is this auto mount feature configured?
- how do I get this auto mount behaviour to work on my new laptop?

---

update:

googling the first bullet I found:

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/hardware-cardreader.html.en

with the suggestion to open the Files in the Activities list and do control-L and search for `computer:///` . This made the sd card visible. This does not solve my second question, but if this had a solution, it would be mentioned there, and anyway this is a workable situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there is no technical problem, but a new Ubuntu GUI. In the Files activity, under `Other Locations`, the SD card shows up in a very intuitive way, similar to Computer overview of Windows. To me it seems that this top level overview is rather hidden here.

The documentation in https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/hardware-cardreader.html.en is not exactly in sync, as it mentions a device list in the side bar, not under Other Locations.

On my previous ubuntu system a popup would appear at insertion of a usb drive. Removal of the popup could be a feature or a bug :-)

Comment: There should be a schema in `gsettings` for displaying mounted devices on desktop. Obviously not a popup but a viable workaround. Unfortunately I no longer have the usual Ubuntu desktop, so can't provide which exact schema should be altered.