# automount of SD card not working in 21.10

Tags: automount, sd-card

Since updating to Ubuntu 21.10 the automount (and therefore the Gnome Extension "Removable Drive Menu") doesn't work. I have to open Nautilus and click on the SD card entry to mount an SD card. How can I have the automount feature of all Ubuntu revisions since I started using Ubuntu with 10.04, back.

Be aware that this is not a duplicate of [internal sd card reader works, but without automount](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058501/internal-sd-card-reader-works-but-without-automount) as that, nor any of the similar posts, doesn't offer a way to automount an SD card in 21.10.

Comment: I am having the same problem, but with a flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Eject and remove all external drives.
Check none is left:

```
ls -l /media/yourlogin (or sudo ls -l /media/yourlogin)

sudo rmdir /media/yourlogin
```

Insert your external drive. /media/yourlogin should be created again.

I had this issue after I changed my UID.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion but it unfortunately didn't solve my problem. The SD card only appears in 'media/yourlogin' after clicking on it in Nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

I found that running `lspci -v` somehow triggers the mounting of the SD card.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1204465)

Comment: @Someone How does this not answer it? It provides a command that answers the question. Wrong answers get downvoted, but not deleted AFAIK.