# Realtek 5287 PCIe controller for memory card reader not reading all cards

Tags: drivers, 16.04, mount, realtek, sd-card

A new System 76 Lemur laptop has a Realtek 5287 PCIe cardreader.

It reads some SD cards but not all. Not to say which it reads or not. System 76 says they are aware of the problem, but don't know how to solve it. I searched and came along many *possible* options, but none seem to work.

System 76 had a similar problem some years ago with another Realtek cardreader, which they posted to Launchpad:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/971876

But that problem has been resolved in the meantime.

Apparently Ubuntu 16.04.1 can't read and/or see all cards, which is a bit weird. It sees for example a SanDisk Ultra 40MB/s 32GB card, some cheap 2GB sd-cards, but none of my 16GB cards (which are from different brands, one SanDisk 16GB Extreme Pro, one Integral Ultima Pro. Both 16GB cards give an error), dmesg shows (first a 16GB one and then 32GB which mounts properly):

```
[ 5861.429822] mmc0: cannot verify signal voltage switch
[ 5864.998521] mmc0: tuning execution failed
[ 5864.998532] mmc0: error -22 whilst initialising SD card
[ 5873.953821] mmc0: cannot verify signal voltage switch
[ 5874.083407] mmc0: new ultra high speed SDR50 SDHC card at address aaaa
[ 5874.083697] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SL32G 29.7 GiB
[ 5874.102882] mmcblk0: p1
[ 5874.286794] FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[ 5891.088486] mmc0: card aaaa removed
```

The unproper unmounting of the volume has nothing to do with Ubuntu and did not have any effect on the readability from the card.

I tried blacklisting the

```
rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
```

modules. Made no difference. Some cards would mount, some not, with same error messages.

Found some similar problems on Askubuntu:

[Ubuntu 16.04 does not detect sd card reader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787088/ubuntu-16-04-does-not-detect-sd-card-reader)

[SD card not working :[ 249.480884] mmc0: error -5 whilst initialising SD card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776459/sd-card-not-working-249-480884-mmc0-error-5-whilst-initialising-sd-card)

For sure lsmod:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
binfmt_misc            20480  1
mmc_block              36864  0
ctr                    16384  1
ccm                    20480  1
pci_stub               16384  1
vboxpci                24576  0
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxdrv               454656  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
rfcomm                 69632  0
ec_sys                 16384  1
bnep                   20480  2
arc4                   16384  2
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
drbg                   32768  1
ansi_cprng             16384  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
dm_crypt               28672  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
snd_hda_intel          40960  5
kvm_intel             172032  0
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
kvm                   540672  1 kvm_intel
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
iwlmvm                311296  0
aesni_intel           167936  16769
mac80211              737280  1 iwlmvm
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
uvcvideo               90112  0
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
cryptd                 20480  8386 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              176128  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
iwlwifi               200704  1 iwlmvm
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
input_leds             16384  0
joydev                 20480  0
serio_raw              16384  0
snd                    81920  20 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
cfg80211              565248  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
shpchp                 36864  0
mei_me                 36864  0
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
hci_uart               77824  0
btbcm                  16384  2 btusb,hci_uart
btqca                  16384  1 hci_uart
btintel                16384  2 btusb,hci_uart
bluetooth             520192  31 bnep,btbcm,btqca,btrtl,btusb,hci_uart,rfcomm,btintel
intel_lpss_acpi        16384  0
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_acpi
acpi_pad               20480  0
mac_hid                16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
btrfs                 987136  0
xor                    24576  1 btrfs
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
raid6_pq              102400  1 btrfs
dm_mirror              24576  0
dm_region_hash         24576  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 20480  2 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
i915_bpo             1302528  6
intel_ips              20480  1 i915_bpo
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915_bpo
drm_kms_helper        155648  1 i915_bpo
psmouse               131072  0
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
r8169                  81920  0
nvme                   65536  4
drm                   364544  7 i915_bpo,drm_kms_helper
mii                    16384  1 r8169
rtsx_pci               53248  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
ahci                   36864  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
wmi                    20480  0
pinctrl_sunrisepoint    28672  0
i2c_hid                20480  0
video                  40960  1 i915_bpo
pinctrl_intel          20480  1 pinctrl_sunrisepoint
hid                   118784  3 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid
fjes                   28672  0
```

Anyone any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Edit: I received one possible solution for certain cards by System 76:

```
sudo apt install exfat-utils
```

Which unfortunately does not work for all card types, mainly not for ultra/elite/extreme cards (like mine). But maybe a solution for some.